# How do I install the latest version of pytest, coexisting with an older version?

Tags: version, pytest, upgrade

Here is my current version

```
% pytest --version
This is pytest version 4.6.9, imported from /home/abc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest.pyc
```

Per https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/announce/index.html, the latest version is **pytest-5.4.1**.

I ran `% pip install --upgrade pytest` but my pytest version still remains as 4.6.9. Ideally, I'd like to be able to install the latest version separately, something like pytest3.

I have both python 2.x and 3.x on my machine.

Comment: Go to site package and change the pytest directory name to something else and then install the second version

Comment: Run `pip -V` and (if your `pip` is of a version 20.0 and newer) `pip debug` and add the output to the question. Most probably you have multiple Python installations in your system, the `pip` command installs for one installation and you are expecting package updates in another one.

Comment: My pip version: `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried uninstalling pytest

python3 windows

```
pip uninstall pytest
```

python3 linux

```
pip3 uninstall pytest
```

then install again

```
pip install pytest
```

or
download whl file from 
https://pypi.org/project/pytest/#files
download the pytest-5.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
package.
then go to terminal or cmd for windows.

commands:

```
pip3 uninstall pytest
cd Desktop

pip3 install pytest-5.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

or

```
pip uninstall pytest
cd Desktop
pip install pytest-5.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

please tell me if you want me to explain more

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed but it made no difference.

Comment: what operating system are you on

Comment: have you looked at this site https://pypi.org/project/pytest/

Comment: I'm using `WSL` on Windows10. I looked at the pytest link but still couldn't figure out.

Comment: commands: ```pip3 uninstall pytest``` next command ```cd Downloads``` next command: ```wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/e2/c19c667f42f72716a7d03e8dd4d6f63f47d39feadd44cc1ee7ca3089862c/pytest-5.4.1-py3-none-any.whl``` next command: ```pip3 install pytest-5.4.1-py3-none-any.whl```